# How to Write python program execution status/Logging to Snowflake Table?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script which runs periodically. I want to write the
status of the script (SUCCESS / FAILED ) back to a logging table in on snowflake.

I am doing tracing but that does not seem to solve my problem.

```
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)
tracer.run('main()')
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True)
```

What I am looking for is to generate a row in the event the script completes successfully, and a row if the script fails.
Is `try / exception` the only method. I don't want to wrap the entire code in a single `try/catch` block because there are many function and each of them has their own block.

How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to wrap the outer most call, the main call, with the try except.

```
failed = False
try:
    main()
except:
    failed = True
    write_failure()
if not failed:
    write_success()
```